# Real world report data size for Hockeyapp

Tags: hockeyapp

I am writing a mobile app and am soon moving to the stage of inviting alpha and beta testers through Hockeyapp.

Due to the app target audience, testing and resulting crash and usage reporting will be through clogged and slow mobile networks in regional/rural Australia. On top of that data quotas tend to be small and expensive.

Hockeyapp's documentation states that crash reports are small in size and designed to "go through" even in flaky mobile networks. This documentation states that crash files can be as small as 200KB.

That should be sufficiently small to allow reports to go through even in "one bubble" areas, but as someone who experiences outages and dead zones daily, I'm interested to preemptively find optimisations and work-arounds.

- **Regardless** of what Hockeyapp claims, are the real world report sizes
  sufficiently small to reliably make it through unreliable mobile
  network zones? Has anyone with a similar deployment scenario found that the claim align with actual usage?
- What work-around beyond the documented use of the class libraries may
  be needed to ensure reports go through? Especially to go through
  fully and not constant resend attempts of aborted reports, which
  would all drive up used quota.

The specific application used Xamarin for cross-platform development, which had the disadvantage of incurring overhead is app size compared to native application environments, e.g. iOS.

Edit: rephrasing for clarification of questions.

Comment: As this is a specific question on HockeyApp, please contact their support. In addition their SDKs are all open source, so it should be pretty easy to verify and check.

Comment: @Kerni Not sure my question is one for support: I've read the docs, I've checked their forums. This is a "real world" vs "what the docs say". Not the least because they're not an Australian company - our mobile system in rural areas is something like out of the so-called Third World. :(

Comment: Either support to get in touch with the developers or create a ticket on a specific GitHub project. It is for sure a specific question for the HockeyApp product and not something that is of general interest for what StackOverflow is for. Support is the way to get in touch with the products team and get your question answered.

Comment: I'm sorry but that makes no sense. How are the majority of questions on Stackoverflow NOT in some way product specific, if they pertain to a specific product? If I ask a question on building, say, an addon for Atlassian Jira, should I also go to support and not on SE?! That would invalidate thousands of questions on here. Oh, and that's not even taking into account that a major reason for the existence of SE is that support is frequently insufficient and this is a valid alternative.